# Calling a method from one class to another to get its value

Tags: java, class, if-statement, methods

```
package Multiplemethods;

import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class TimeOffice {
    
public static void main(String args[]){
//instance variables
double[] intime = {09.34,09.56,09.00,08.55};
double[] outtime = {17.25,18.06,17.55,16.00};
double[] loginhours = new double[intime.length];


 //subtracting two arrays 
 
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<intime.length;i++)
    loginhours [i] = outtime[i]-intime[i];

    for(int j =0; j< loginhours.length; j++)

    System.out.print("Login hours=" + loginhours[j] + ",");

//sum working hours calculation
double sum = DoubleStream.of(loginhours).sum();
System.out.println("Total workinghours="+ sum);

//average working hours calculation
double average = sum/4;
System.out.println("Average working hours=" + average);
    

//instant variable (leave) Total leaves calculation
    int leave = 2;
    int Totalleaves = leave +1;
    System.out.println("Total leaves taken=" + Totalleaves);
}

  public class Payroll extends TimeOffice{
    
    //instance variables
    int level = 3;
    int basicpay = 12000;
    int BOA = 9000 ;
    int Bonus = 3000 ;
  }
```

}

I have calculated the average of `loginhours` in the class `TimeOffice`. Now, I have created a new class called `Payroll` and want to call the method `average` here, so that I can give proceed with if conditions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You did not create a method for finding average, you only have a `main`.  You need to create a method such as `public static double findAverage(int...values)` in order to use your code in another location.  I suggest searching up tutorials on methods with examples to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why is class `Payroll` as well an inner class of `TimeOffice` and also inheriting from it? Please use any standard coding conventions or be at least consistent with your namings. (`Totalleaves` should be `totalLeaves` or `totalLeaveCount`. And finally: please show the intended use of your `Payroll` class - even if it does not do what you want yet.